# Why React doesn't render the new created post correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

MERN stack, It's a simple CRUD to learn node and express alongside with React.

I'm trying to understand why when I create a new post, the post renders on the page and then disappear.

As soon as I try to create a new post, the post renders on the screen for 5 seconds, then disappears completely after that time.

It's something in the code? The `useEffect` accepts a dependency array with everything it needs inside. So I don't understand where's the problem.

Can you help me, guys?

**CLIENT SIDE**

this is the `useEffect` in App.js

```
import { getPosts } from '../src/actions/posts';

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts())
}, [currentId, dispatch]);
```

the API calls

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
```

the reducer

```
export const posts = (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LIKE':
        case 'UPDATE':
            return posts.map(post => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post)

        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...posts, action.payload];

        case 'DELETE':
            return posts.filter(post => post._id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}
```

the actions

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createPost(post);
        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE', payload: data })
        console.log('created')
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

**SERVER SIDE**

the route

```
import { createPost, getPosts } from '../controllers/posts.js';

router.post('/', createPost);
router.get('/', getPosts);
```

the controller

```
export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const postMessages = await PostMessage.find()
        res.status(200).json(postMessages)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message })
    }
};

export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const { title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags } = req.body;

    const newPostMessage = new PostMessage({ title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags })

    try {
        await newPostMessage.save();

        res.status(201).json(newPostMessage);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

**POST COMPONENT**

```
import React from 'react';
import useStyles from './styles';
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import MoreHorizIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz';
import moment from 'moment';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { deletePost, likePost } from '../../../actions/posts';

const Post = ({ post, setCurrentId }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={post.selectedFile || 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/194400/49531010-48dad180-f8b1-11e8-8d89-1e61320e1d82.png'} title={post.title} />
            <div className={classes.overlay}>
                <Typography variant="h6">
                    {post.creator}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">
                    {moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}
                </Typography>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.overlay2}>
                <Button style={{ color: "#fff" }} size="small" onClick={() => setCurrentId(post._id)}>
                    <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="medium" />
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.details}>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                    {post.tags.map(tag => tag ? `#${tag} ` : '')}
                </Typography>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.title}>
                <Typography className={classes.excerpt} variant="body2" color="textPrimary">
                    {post.title}
                </Typography>
            </div>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textPrimary">
                    {post.message}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
                <Button className={classes.likeBtn} size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => dispatch(likePost(post._id))}>
                    <span>
                        <ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize="small" />
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.like}>
                        {post.likeCount ? post.likeCount : ''}
                    </span>
                </Button>
                <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => dispatch(deletePost(post._id))}>
                    <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
                    Delete
                </Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Post
```

Comment: What the view/component looks like?

Comment: I've updated the question with the whole post component, also I forgot to say that only when I refresh (obviosuly) the post reappears.